# Windows 10 1803 Pro 64 bit: "print driver host for application" shows a preview Window

Tags: windows-10, printing

I have a PC with Win 10 Pro 1803 and everytime I print something from any printer and any application, an application called "print driver host for application" with exe name "splwow64.exe" shows a Preview window.

Is there any way to avoid this window?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably an option in your printer's configuration.

In the dialog for choosing a printer, click the *Properties* button near to the
printer's name and search for a preview option to unselect.

Here is an example :

[image]